# Toolbar color of CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

On the state collapse of collapsingToolbar color gets purely white for android 11 and it remains black (required behavior) for android 10 and below can anyone explain what's actually went wrong while implementing CollapsingToolbarLayout.

Thank you! :)

MainApplication.kt

```
class MainApplication : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        // THEME DARK    
   AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
   ...
   }
}
```

themes.xml

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
...
</style>
<style name="Theme.MyApp.AppBarOverlay"  parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="Theme.MyApp.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

activity_main.xml

```
 <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/app_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApp.AppBarOverlay">
        
                <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                ...
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="@android:color/black"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
                 
                <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                        app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.MyApp.PopupOverlay" />
        
                </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout> 
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

This is for android 10 and below:
[image]

This is for android 11 Toolbar getting white:
[image]

Common for all android version - Expanded state Toolbar:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior was only found in MIUI 11 and above.

The solution is Found!

```
<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">true</item>
```

Setting false to the above attribute in App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/values/styles.xml